# Floating Point with 2 Digits after Point

Tags: android, formatting, floating-point

I will Format a Floating Point Number in android with 2 Digits after the point.
I search for a Example but i din´t find one.

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 90):

```
float f = 2.3455f;  
String test = String.format("%.02f", f);
```

Comment: This gives a warning: "Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use String.format(Locale, ...) instead"

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `DecimalFormat`

```
float f = 102.236569f; 
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
float twoDigitsF = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(f)); // output is 102.24
//double twoDigitsF = Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(f)); also format double value
```

Answer (score 3):

In answer above it always will return 2 deciaml

examples with String.format("%.02f", f)

2.5555 -> 2.55

2.5    -> 2.50

**but do you need to get 2.50 for 2.5?**

for avoid to get excessive 0, you can use this solution

```
val format = DecimalFormat("0.##")
return format.format(floatNum)
```